# CLLocation in multiple view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios

i need to use GPS in two different views. i have it set up in my first view controller, but trying to figure out how to do it in the second view.

what is a good approach to do this? use a different CCLocationManager for each view? set up a notification in first view controller to tell the second view controller to get updated GPS from first view controller?

Comment: Question looks similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510341/ios-core-location-where-to-put-code/8510415#8510415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you set up one instance of the location manager to update in one place (such as the app delegate), and then set up key value observing on that location to send you a notification when it is changed. Here are some Apple docs on KVO:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Answer (score 1):

I made the variables that I needed available across multiple views global - it's the easiest solution.  If you would like, you could create an object that only contained these variables, that would at least compartmentalize them.

Comment: in my first view controller, i do save the values to my appdelegate which i use as a data center. i can get the update values from there, but my second view controller would have no idea when the value updates/changes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a singleton object, CLLocationManager delegate. It will manage GPS data and any view will be able to retrieve it.